Laravel RestClientException For 201 Response
I am using RestClient to make request to the thirdparty api.
I am using the following code
try {
    $payload = [
        "email" => $user->email,
        "groups" => [
            $this->free_group_id
        ]
    ];

    $api_result = $this->client->post('/api/subscribers', $payload);

    $user->mailerlite_id = $api_result["data"]["id"];
    $user->save();
} catch (RestClientException $e) {
    Log::debug($e->getHttpCode());
    Log::debug($e->getCode());
    Log::debug($e->getMessage());
    Log::debug($e->getTraceAsString());

    $user->mailerlite_id = $api_result["data"]["id"];
    $user->save();
}

But even if the post request succeeds, RestClientException arises
The response's httpcode is 201 (created) and I think this shouldn't be treated as exception.
Am I wrong? or Is this just a bug in the library?

Indeed, 201 is a success code and should probably not raise an exception.

What's the debug output?
